# delphi TClientDataSet utf-8

Tags: delphi, ms-access, utf-8, tclientdataset

everybody!

I try to load data into oIntermediateStream in way like that:

```
    oIntermediateStream : TStringStream;
    oClient := TClientDataSet.Create(MainOpScr);
    oClient.LoadFromStream(oIntermediateStream);
```

The problem is I want to see one unicode simbol - 'қ'. But I see it in my MSACCESS database like two symbols - 'Т›' ( in windows-1251 encoding).
I suspected something wrong with my base but if I insert this symbol by clipboard I see correct view of my symbol.?

I am looking now on TXMLTransform, but I am not sure it is rigth way?

Could you advise something, please.

Comment: what version of delphi ?

Comment: You say you see it in your MS Access database like so. What exactly are you looking at? Access itself? A data grid? A string you obtained? What does Access have to do with your client dataset code?

Comment: Delphi 2007. I look it in a table in access itself. But if I see it in access then I see it correct in my app (not my own in fact) - in all controls.

Comment: I think it is because utf-8 is not supported in Delphi2007 ...